# How do I add each element into a list?

Tags: racket

So Im' trying to print out a list of numbers but instead of printing all the numbers only the last number is put into the list. I know that means that the other numbers are not being inserted but I dont know how to fix this problem. I tried moving my cons around the function but nothign changes.

I'm new to racket so if Im not understanding a concept, please let me know.

should look like:

```
(gen-list 1 4)
```

output:

```
'(1 2 3 4)
```

```
(define (gen-list start end)
  (if (> start end)
      '()
      (cond ((<= start end)
             (gen-list start (- end 1))
             )))
  (cons end '()))
```

Comment: Your procedure is equivalent to `(define (gen-list start end) (cons end '()))`. With proper indentation, you can see that the body contains two expressions; the conditional and `(cons end '())`. The latter is the function's result.

Comment: Also, `(<= start end)` must be true, since the `if` has established that `(> start end)` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I see you would like to use recursion, so I would suggest to use `printf` to understand what really happen.

The idea is quite simple, you have `start` and `end`, what you want to have is the following:

- Step 1: start=1 end=4
- Step 2: start=2 end=4
- Step 3: start=3 end=4
- Step 4: start=4 end=4
- Step 5: start=5 end=4, here we stop the recursion

So you need to `increment start` at each step of the `recursion` when the condition is met `(<= start end)`.

```
(define (gen-list start end)
  (printf "CALL ~A ~A~%" start end)
  (cond
    ((<= start end)
      (cons start
            (gen-list (+ start 1) end)))
    (else '())))

(gen-list 1 4)
```

Will return:

```
CALL 1 4
CALL 2 4
CALL 3 4
CALL 4 4
CALL 5 4
'(1 2 3 4)
```

EDIT: if you concern is to write programs, you could also use built-in functions, which are ready for use:

```
> (range 1 5)
(1 2 3 4)

> (sequence->list (in-inclusive-range 1 4))
'(1 2 3 4)

> (build-list 4 (lambda (x) x))
'(0 1 2 3)
```

https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sequences.html